# Does DISM CheckHealth need either internet or Windows ISO to give an accurate result?

Tags: windows-10, dism, sfc

Using an elevated command prompt, on a PC without an internet connection or a downloaded Windows 10 ISO, I entered:

`Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth`

It takes a few seconds, with the result:

> No component store corruption detected. The operation completed successfully.

How does it know it is not corrupted, when it has no access to Windows Update nor an ISO to check against?

(I would like to know I can trust this result.)

Background:

- SFC VerifyOnly said: "Windows Resource Protection found integrity violations."
- Before using SFC ScanNow I wanted to check for corrupted files with DISM.
- I have a Windows 10 ESD-ISO DVD, however `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:esd:E:\sources\install.esd:1 /limitaccess` does not access the DVD. It gives the result "The restore operation completed successfully. The operation completed successfully." without spinning the DVD.
- I used SFC (after scans for malware, with none found) because Windows Firewall keeps turning off and won't turn back on. After the PC is restarted the firewall is back on.

Comment: Run `chkdsk`. If it finds nothing, post somewhere the file `C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log`.

Answer (score 0):

If your system is working near properly, DISM does not need to do this. Make a backup of important documents (just in case) and run with the Restorehealth option. You probably will need Internet for this

If that fails, run a Windows 10 Repair Install to fix your system. Use the Download link, run in place and at the appropriate spot, start with Keep Everything.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10